# Making the access to a Fast API on AWS private

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, fastapi

I've created an EC2 instance where I want to serve a FAST API. I made the instance that I've created to be public (everyone can access the link. e.g. http://1.23.45.678/docs/). Then, I used [nginx](https://lcalcagni.medium.com/deploy-your-fastapi-to-aws-ec2-using-nginx-aa8aa0d85ec7) to forward the calls from the EC2 instance IP to the local FAST API address (which is the localhost).

Now, I'd like to make this API to be private. One solution that I've found is to use [API key authentication](https://joshdimella.com/blog/adding-api-key-auth-to-fast-api) to set a key. Is this going to make my API safe? or do I have to do something else with the EC2 instance?

This is for personal use, so I have no VPN or whatever.

Comment: Are you looking to make it private in such a way that A) People could not hit your servers on the network level? B) people could not call your APIs using tools like postman? C) Does your API have any user-based authentication system?

Comment: I want to make it private in a way that if someone reached it, they have to use a key to run it. which is the way I am doing now. but I am not sure if this is fine as the server IP is public.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll give a short answer and then the real answer.

Based on your post and your comment, yes, API keys are *probably* sufficient for what you’re looking for, but that comes with a list of caveats.

FWIW the blog post you shared doesn’t use constant time comparison when checking the input API key against the list of known API keys and is vulnerable to a side channel timing attack.

Ok now for the long answer without trying to sound too much like a pedant …

Authentication isn’t the only thing that contributes to securing a web app. For example, API keys alone don’t encrypt network traffic between you and the API. API keys don’t keep the operating system up to date on the EC2 system, they don’t ensure the SSH server on the EC2 instance is configured securely. API keys can’t really prevent an authenticated user from exploiting vulnerable code in your API.

My point is, many things work to keep an API “safe” so implementing authentication on your FastAPI application doesn’t necessarily qualify as “safe”, but it does seem to meet your goal. The blog post you shared basically acts as a rudimentary hard-coded password.

Take a look at [OWASP Top Ten](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/) for anyone rolling their eyes at timing side channel attacks. Cryptographic failures is #2.

I’d configure nginx Basic Authentication rather than use what’s in that blog post. Then make sure you’re using TLS with an HTTPS redirect, and make sure your FastAPI app is not running as root, and make sure nginx isn’t running as root. If you’re the only one using the API and you’re connecting from a static IP or a dynamic IP that doesn’t change often, you could also modify the security group on the EC2 instance to only accept inbound connections from your own IP address.

Comment: Thanks @Sam for your answer.
I just want to mention that, there is nothing really critical in the API. It's just an ML API that processes text. I just mentioned this because I felt that your answer is more related to data-sensitive API. For me, I just want to make sure that: 1) no one can access the server? 2) no one can use the API?

Comment: I think nginx basic auth would be a better fit.